# Extern Command C and Python

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to call a extern variable cwdata in my C and Python integration. This is my file randomGoppa.c

```
extern precomp_t cwdata;
static PyObject* dicho(PyObject* self, PyObject* args){
  unsigned char * c;
  int * e;
  PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "ii", &c, &e);
  int i = dicho_b2cw(cwdata);
}

static PyMethodDef randomGoppa_methods[] = {{ "dicho",dicho, METH_VARARGS},
{NULL, NULL}};

void initrandomGoppa() {
(void) Py_InitModule("randomGoppa", randomGoppa_methods);
}
```

When I compile using

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -o randomGoppa.so randomGoppa.c mat.c poly.c gf.c dicho.c
```

is not there erros. but I get error when in python I try to import

```
from randomGoppa import *

lib/python2.7/site-packages/randomGoppa.so: undefined symbol: cwdata
```

Can someone explain what happens here?

Comment: Where is your `cwdata` *defined*? The `extern` tells the compiler that the variable will be defined in a different module that will be linked in the future. So one of the C files you pass to GCC must *define* (not `extern`) the variable.

Comment: @chrisaycock the cwdata is defined in the first line of randomGoppa.c

Comment: No, it is not. By using the "extern" keyword, you tell C there that a symbol with the name cwdata exists somewhere, but you do not define it in the sense of memory allocation etc. See p.e. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_variable).

Comment: @user46060 Glad that was the culprit. I've made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `cwdata` with an `extern`. That causes the compiler to not allocate space for the variable, which is why it isn't defined. (The compiler expects the variable to be defined in a different module that will be linked in the future.) Since you intended to define `cwdata` in that C file, just remove the `extern` keyword.